# why and how these two maps are equal, and how they find the norm?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $\{u_1,\cdots, u_k\}$ and $\{w_1, \cdots w_k\}$ be finite sets in $\Bbb M_n$. We can then define a linear map $\varphi:\Bbb M_n\to\Bbb M_n$ by $$\varphi(x)=\sum_ju_j\cdot x\cdot w_j.$$ What is the norm of $\varphi$? That is, compute $\Vert\varphi\Vert=\sup\{\vert\varphi(x)\Vert:\Vert x\Vert\le1\}$.

$M_n$ is just set of all $n\times n$ complex matrices.

> The triangle inequality show trivially that $$\Vert\varphi\Vert\le\sum_j\Vert u_j\Vert \Vert w_j\Vert.$$ Identify $\Bbb C^n \otimes \Bbb C^k$ with $\Bbb C^{nk}$. In $\Bbb C^k$, let $\{\delta_1,\cdots,\delta_k\}$ be the standard basis.
>
> Then we can define maps $$u,w:\Bbb C^n\to\Bbb C^n \otimes \Bbb C^k;\quad u(\xi)=\sum_j u^*_j(\xi)\otimes\delta_j,\quad w(\xi)=\sum_j w_j(\xi)\otimes \delta_j.$$ Then
> $$\varphi(x)=u^*(x\otimes I)w\implies \Vert \varphi \Vert\le\Vert u^*\Vert\Vert w\Vert=\left\Vert\sum_ju_ju_j^*\right\Vert^{1/2}\left\Vert\sum_jw_j^*w_j\right\Vert^{1/2}$$

Could anyone tell me how to show $\varphi(x)=u^*(x\otimes I)w$? It is the last line that I do not understand. What is $x$ there? I may be wrong but  $$w:\mathbb{C}^n\to\mathbb{C}^n\otimes\mathbb{C}^k$$ $$x\otimes I:\mathbb{C}^n\otimes\mathbb{C}^k\to \mathbb{C}^n\otimes\mathbb{C}^k$$ $$u^*:\mathbb{C}^n\otimes\mathbb{C}^k\to\mathbb{C}^n$$ I do not understand why they are equal. I would be grateful if somebody could explain it. Thank you.
Edit: I have understood that $x\in M_n(\mathbb{C}),I$ is $k\times k$ identity matrix so $x\otimes I:\mathbb{C}^n\otimes\mathbb{C}^k\to$ itself a linear map.

Now to be they equal enough to show where they sends the basis elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we must see what is the action of $u^*$. This can be done, seeing that
$$\langle\eta\otimes\zeta,u(\delta_i)\rangle=\langle u^*(\eta\otimes\zeta),\delta_i\rangle,$$
and
\begin{align}\langle\eta\otimes\zeta,u(\delta_i)\rangle&=\sum_j\langle\eta\otimes\zeta,u_j^*(\delta_i)\otimes\delta_j\rangle \\
&=\sum_j\langle\eta,u_j^*(\delta_i)\rangle\langle\zeta,\delta_j\rangle \\
&=\sum_j\langle u_j(\eta),\delta_i\rangle\langle\zeta,\delta_j\rangle \\
&=\left<\sum_j\langle\delta_j,\zeta\rangle u_j(\eta),\delta_i\right>
\end{align}
Hence
$$u^*(\eta\otimes\zeta)=\sum_j\langle\delta_j,\zeta\rangle u_j(\eta)$$
We have then
\begin{align}u^*(x\otimes I)w(\xi)&=u^*(x\otimes I)\sum_jw_j(\xi)\otimes\delta_j\\
&=u^*\left(\sum_jxw_j(\xi)\otimes\delta_j\right) \\
&=\sum_i\sum_j\langle\delta_i,\delta_j\rangle u_ixw_j(\xi) \\
&=\sum_i\sum_j\delta_{ij}u_ixw_j(\xi) \\
&=\sum_ju_jxw_j(\xi) \\
&=\varphi(x)(\xi)
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you very much, I have understood your explanation, but how the norm inequality at the end came?could you help that to understand?

Comment: The first inequality is only about compostition of operators: $\|AB\|\leq\|A\|\|B\|$. The second one uses the fact that the norm of an operator $A$ in a finite dimensional space is given by $\|A\|=\|A^*A\|^{1/2}$.

Comment: thanks a lot, yes yes, I have proved the fact $\|A\|^2=\|A^*A\|$

Comment: could you please tell me the answer of this question? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/976923/how-to-understood-this-tensor-product-map